# multiple modal windows with js css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making multiple modal windows , although I am repeating myself.  If I could see a different approach to the javascript in order to make this more terse I would definitely appreciate it. And I will pay it forward when I am a ninja....

thanks in advance.  here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcus_sustain/EBpjk/).
I created two modal's,  two mask's and  two modal content areas.  I also created an img link and a button link.   One for each modal respectively.   I would like use the function to open any modal windiow.....

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.createElement` to dynamically create new modals.

```
function createModal(txt){
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.id = "modal";
    document.body.appendChild(ele);

    var mask = document.createElement("div");
    mask.id = "modalMask";
    mask.onclick = function(){
        ele.outerHTML = "";
    }
    ele.appendChild(mask);

    var inside = document.createElement("div");
    inside.id = "modalContent";
    inside.innerHTML = txt;
    ele.appendChild(inside);
}
createModal("Content here");


//do more stuff here
```

And you will have to remove the `div` when the user clicks "close".